# Cloning MongoDB database with MongoDB Compass

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-compass

Is there a way to Clone a MongoDB database and its data with MongoDB Compass to my local server? I do not want to corrupt the dev environment by accident so I want to test things out locally, but I can't find a solution for that on MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB Compass has a great documentation explaining how you can import/export one collection at the time for both JSON and CSV files.

I think that there is no better answer than the link to the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/import-export#import-data-into-a-collection

Comment: Question talks about copying databases not copying all collections. To export data mongo dump should be used.

Answer (score 0):

To clone **an existing database** to **a new one**, use the `mongodump` and `mongorestore` commands.

To dump DB:

```
mongodump -d <database_name> -o <directory_backup>
```

To clone DB:

```
mongorestore -d <new_database_name> <directory_backup>/<database_name>
```